# select a row twice from same table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that uses connect by prior to derive the values in a hierarchical
way,

```
SELECT  EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID FROM TABLE 
WHERE
EMP_STATUS = 'A'
AND LEVEL <=15
START WITH EMP_id ='XXXXXXX'
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMP_ID = SUPERVISOR_ID;
```

Now I need to display the rows twice with supervisor_id value hard coded in one of the row. The desired output is,

```
EMP_ID1 NAME1 SUPERVISOR_ID1
EMP_ID1 NAME1 HARDCODED_VALUE
EMP_ID2 NAME2 SUPERVISOR_ID2
EMP_ID2 NAME2 HARDCODED_VALUE
```

Will connect by prior and group by work together? I can use UNION ALL to display the row twice but not sure how to deal with the hard coded value. Suggestions please.

Comment: If you're using Oracle, then why have you tagged MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using `union all`:

```
WITH t AS (
      SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID
      FROM TABLE 
      WHERE EMP_STATUS = 'A' AND
            LEVEL <= 15
      START WITH EMP_id ='XXXXXXX'
      CONNECT BY PRIOR EMP_ID = SUPERVISOR_ID
     )
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, 'HARDCODED_VALUE'
FROM t;
```

If you want the data in a particular order, then you should use an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, 'HARDCODED_VALUE'
FROM t
ORDER BY EMP_ID,
         (CASE WHEN SUPERVISOR_ID <> 'HARDCODED_VALUE' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Comment: Tried this. Result not in the expected format. I need it like two entries for an employee one with actual value followed by hard coded value and then the next employee. It gives like all actual values at once followed by hardcoded one. But this is a good one. Trying to see if I can make some changes on top of this.

Comment: You just need an @mohanakrishnan if you want the results in a particular order.

Comment: If I use order by then the hierarchy breaks.

Comment: @mohanakrishnan . . . Add a counter to the hierarchy and use that for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

try this one with union:

```
SELECT  EMP_ID, 'NAME1', SUPERVISOR_ID FROM TABLE
```

good luck!
Oliver

Comment: Both connect by prior and order by should work. Already tired this and didnt get the expected result